# Using Stanford Dependencies in python stanfordnlp (rather than Universal Dependencies)

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to reproduce a study into sentiment analysis which uses dependency structures which were generated using the Stanford NLP library, the issue is that the study is from 2011 and I've found that than the Standford library used *Stanford Dependencies* but it now uses *Universal Dependencies* which gives different results (see https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml#English). My query is whether one can still use Stanford dependencies in the stanfordnlp library in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a native Python model, but you could launch a Java Stanford CoreNLP server and get the older dependencies.

This model should use Stanford Dependencies for instance:

```
edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/wsj_SD.gz
```